# How do I find my USB location when it doesn't show up on the side panel even though it is mounted?

Tags: usb-drive

My flash drive is mounted, and when I check in the terminal it says it's mounted, but when I look on the side panel, the flash drive isn't there. So I can't access my flash drive and I have important things that I need to put onto it. How can I access the drive and add files to it?

Comment: With 17.10 and the new environment the drives no longer show up in the "launcher". Try opening the file manager and check there.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and what desktop environment are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If it is mounted, then in Ubuntu it will most likely have its mount point in the /media directory. It may be under a username there So try

```
ls /media/*
```

or

```
ls /media/<user>/*
```

If it is there, then you can put a link to it on your desktop with

```
ln -s /media/<disklocation> ~/Desktop
```

Comment: Factual and the link suggestion is likely useful. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find the mount location with the `Disks` application AKA gnome-disk-utility. See below:

[image: disks]

Clicking on the link next to "Mounted at" will open the location in your file manager.